# Rxjava2- Android ( Concat + Zip ) Possible?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

i have two API calls 
1.) Profile Fetch 
2.) Feeds Fetch

i need to load the cache if present , else go for network.

if cache is present load it while the network is been also called in background

using a CONCAT op.
eg. `concat(feedlocal, feednetwork)`

and as soon as the network call is received update the recycle view using DiffUtils (android)

Similarly : `concat(profilelocal, profilenetwork)`

**PROBLEM:**

i am using zip(c1, c2) **(apology if am using thing wrong )**
but problem is the network response is never responded via zip op.

https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/giQolwcSSPZrBxwiUQoFbsQ7FMxBRr8w/4vgkDWPUoU5Pb8sQsLa0bbAURs7gKi0ncyIoluD7bqU2EeOk-FJnJudUvKjB5hwNY0bm7Yt_kl9wgZ5aC4a567PCxpUhnoNxUJWEcO6i0VY89QQDsTU3uZ

i Need to show cache first , and update ui when Network call is received and make it parallel (Feed + Profile)

**EDIT:**

```
  private Observable<List<FeedProfileResponse>> getProfileObservable(){


    //local
    Observable<List<FeedProfileResponse>> local = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
            dataManager.getCacheValueOf(DB_FEED_PROFILE_LIST) != null ?
                    new Gson().fromJson(dataManager.getCacheValueOf(DB_FEED_PROFILE_LIST)
                            , new TypeToken<List<FeedProfileResponse>>() {
                            }.getType()) :
                    Collections.<FeedProfileResponse>emptyList())
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());

    //network
    Observable<List<FeedProfileResponse>> network = apiHelper.fetchFeedProfile(dataManager.getCurrentUserId().intValue()
            , mProfileCurrentPage)
            .map(responses -> {
                //Cache Updates
                Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                    updateCacheDao(dataManager.getCacheObj(DB_FEED_PROFILE_LIST),
                            new Gson().toJson(responses), DB_FEED_PROFILE_LIST,
                            NetworkUtils.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                    subscriber.onComplete();
                })
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.computation())
                .subscribe();


                return responses;
            })
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());


    CacheData cacheObj = dataManager.getCacheObj(DB_FEED_PROFILE_LIST);
    return cacheObj != null ? !NetworkUtils.hasTimestampExpired(cacheObj.getUpdatedAt())
            && cacheObj.getUpdatedAt() > dataManager.getAppTimestamp() ?
            local.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) :
            Observable.concat(local, network).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) : network.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

}

private Observable<List<FeedReviewResponse>> getReviewObservable() {

    //local 
    Observable<List<FeedReviewResponse>> local = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
            dataManager.getCacheValueOf(DB_FEED_REVIEW_LIST) != null ?
                    new Gson().fromJson(dataManager.getCacheValueOf(DB_FEED_REVIEW_LIST)
                            , new TypeToken<List<FeedReviewResponse>>() {
                            }.getType()) :
                    Collections.<FeedReviewResponse>emptyList())
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());

    //network 
    Observable<List<FeedReviewResponse>> network = apiHelper.fetchFeedReviews(dataManager.getCurrentUserId().intValue(),
            AppConstants.FeedReviewConstants.KEY_API_PARAM_1, AppConstants.FeedReviewConstants.KEY_API_PARAM_2,
            mCurrentPage)
            .map(responses -> {
                isFeedReviewLastPage = !(responses.size() == AppConstants.FeedReviewConstants.PAGE_SIZE);

                //Cache Updates
                Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                    updateCacheDao(dataManager.getCacheObj(DB_FEED_REVIEW_LIST),
                            new Gson().toJson(responses), DB_FEED_REVIEW_LIST,
                            NetworkUtils.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                    subscriber.onComplete();
                })
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.computation())
                .subscribe();


                return responses;
            })

            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());


    CacheData cacheObj = dataManager.getCacheObj(DB_FEED_REVIEW_LIST);
    return cacheObj != null ? !NetworkUtils.hasTimestampExpired(cacheObj.getUpdatedAt())
            && cacheObj.getUpdatedAt() > dataManager.getAppTimestamp() ?
            local.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) :
            Observable.concat(local, network).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) : network.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());


}

private void zipProfileAndReview(Observable<List<FeedReviewResponse>> reviewObservable,
                                 Observable<List<FeedProfileResponse>> profileObservable){
    compositeDisposable.add(Observable.zip(reviewObservable, profileObservable,
            ProfileAndReview::new)
            .doOnNext(profileAndReview -> {
                getMvpView().setRefreshing(false);

            })
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .subscribe(profileAndReview -> {
                getMvpView().setFeedReviewListData(profileAndReview.getFeedReviewResponses());
                getMvpView().setFeedProfileListData(profileAndReview.getFeedProfileResponses());

                isFeedReviewLastPage = !(profileAndReview.getFeedReviewResponses().size() == AppConstants.FeedReviewConstants.PAGE_SIZE);
                isFeedProfileLastPage = !(profileAndReview.getFeedProfileResponses().size() == AppConstants.FeedProfileConstants.PAGE_SIZE);

            }, Throwable::printStackTrace));
}
```

Comment: Give us more code please for investigation purpose. Also are you sure network call is never received ? Could be the DiffUtils part which go wrong.

Comment: network call is received but since the disk response is received comparatively fast, so ZIP op take the disk response . and network call is left as it is.  DiffUtil is working well , i have tested it separately.

Answer (score 0):

`getProfileObservable()` and `getReviewObservable()` involve two ternary operators imbricated for the return statement, it's complicate and not readable at all. Are you sure `Observable.concat(local, network)` is the one called during your tests ?

Also a few remarks:

- You should use [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) instead of `zip()` in `zipProfileAndReview`. In order to have all values being processed by `zip()`, you should have the exact same number of value for each of its sources. If one got is cache invalidated or a network call fail, only the first value of the other source would be used. This may even be the source of your problem.
- You should better use `doOnNext()` instead of map for `//Cache Updates` part since you aren't transforming (mapping) the value, just doing side effects.
- You don't need to precise all the way schedulers. Just write once `.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` in `zipProfileAndReview()`.

Comment: Apology for the imbricated  code and thank you for the feed back . i have made the changes with the shared remarks. 
And i have used the Concat op. seperatly, and its working fine. when i add ZIP op. the ZIP op , process the Latest of *reviewObservable and profileObservable*  (either i will be cache or the network data )
 i want to keep the zip alive so that it can also receive the Observable.concat(local, network) network data .

Comment: i am thinking of using Concat op. only and forget about the ZIP op. , thankss for the support .

Comment: Try replacing zip() with combineLatest() as explained to begin with. Then if problem is still here split the return statement of getProfileObservable() in several small function and test them one by one.